# Should I keep the reputation from suggesting edits to deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

As everyone knows, if an edit that I suggest to a question or an answer is approved, I will gain +2 reputation. However, if that post is later deleted, that reputation is removed from my score.

Should the reputation gained from suggested edits be retained even after the post is deleted? I think it should, because the editor has spent his/her time editing the post.

Comment: Yes. The editor wasted their time editing something that was deleted and the rep is removed. It's really unclear what you're asking?

Comment: @TZHX I'm saying the rep should remain for editor cause he waste his time for editing and why deleting question must remove his rep?

Comment: @Arman _"maybe edit rep must remain after delete subject because the editor waste her/his time for edit post?"_ Nope. You probably shouldn't waste your time in polishing turds. That's the moral of the story/lessons learned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ maybe waste is not a good verb for here , I mean he spend his time and should rewarded with rep

Comment: Because the rep is meant to incentivise editing posts to make them better, if the post is deleted either the post was irredeemable or the edit wasn't good enough. And, in general, all rep associated with deleted posts is reversed as part of the deletion.

Comment: @TZHX Maybe deleteing a post has nothing with the edit , so should we always edit good question and good answers and unsalvage questions should remain unedited?

Comment: Encouraging users to turd-polish bad questions is the very last thing the site needs.  Only edit salvageable posts and you won't waste your free time.  And ours.

Comment: @Arman you totally changed the question in the last two lines, you can ask this in a new pots.

Comment: If the question gets deleted, means you lost time with a question not worth the time. Seriously, if you edit a software recommendation question and make the grammar pristine.... you're wasting time. If the question gets deleted, means your edit was either not good enough to warrant the question staying open, or the question was irredeemable to begin with and you should've seen it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, your reputation is an indicator of your contributions to the site. Since the question has been deleted, it is no longer part of the body of content on the site; therefore, you are not awarded reputation for having contributed to it.

In general, you should avoid editing questions that are ultimately *unsalvageable* and will eventually be deleted. This is known colloquially as "turd-polishing," a vulgar euphemism suggesting that you are pursuing a futile attempt to make something better that cannot possibly be made useful.

Of course, it is possible that you misjudge and edit something that the community nevertheless deems unsalvageable. Maybe you thought you could fix it, but really couldn't. Therefore, you are not *punished* for having made these edits. But you are not rewarded. Think of it as an incentive to spend your time more constructively.

Comment: In addition, a "turd polish" edit also wastes the time of the 5 reviewers who are asked to approve or reject the edit.

Comment: I think it is only 3 reviewers for suggested edits, @David. But still—a very good point!