# Should bad questions remain unedited?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Since you get reputation from editing questions or answers, doesn't it discourage people from editing bad questions in fear of their effort amounting to nothing since bad questions may be deleted and cause them to lose their acquired reputation?

Comment: Well, if you edit a bad question and it so becmes a good question, it should not get deleted.  If you edit a bad question and it stays a bad question and gets deleted, what was the point of editing it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you do that on your own risk. If your edit was good enough to make the question useful, and salvage it you will keep your rep, if not you'll not.

Usually it's not possible to salvage bad questions with an edit, unless it will be radically changed, which in turn is unlikely to get the edit approved.

Comment: Indeed, that last point about *suggested* edits is particularly important. Any change that will transform a bad question into a good one is rather unlikely to ever be approved through the suggested edits queue.

Comment: Wait... you lose rep if you edit a closed/closing question?

Comment: @MeirionHughes We were talking about deleted questions.

Comment: @Meirion No. What happens is that you lose the +2 reputation gained by having a suggested edit approved when the edited question is *deleted*. You aren't really losing anything, you just don't get to keep the rep earned for deleted questions. This question was prompted by [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317354/should-i-keep-the-reputation-from-suggesting-edits-to-deleted-posts).

Comment: Okay cool; I misread this. :D

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Doesn't editing a question that's been flagged also cause those flags to be disputed?

Comment: @BSMP I don't know, ask the mods.