# Why does removal of a question after a long time revert the Rep AND PRIVILEGES gained on approved edits?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, privileges

The question in reference [now deleted] is linked here - [Managing Cookies in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228693/managing-cookies-in-angularjs).

I've checked an existing answer [user-was-removed-event-why-are-editing-reputation-points-rolled-back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413/2435357) according to which the following situation should also not occur. Here it is as follows:

2 edits were made by me and approved on **21 July 2017**, which resulted in +4 Rep and a **Comment Everywhere** Privilege.

On **21 September 2017**, the question was removed, resulting in loss of the 4 Rep and also the loss of the Comment Everywhere Privilege.

I've gone through posts about reputation changes on user/post deletion, and I've understood that allowing rep to stay might lead to abuse.

How? Given that suggested edits are put in review queues and then approved by humans, how can there be scope of abuse?

I could be wrong with my above assumption, in which case, I still fail to understand how the appreciation of a valid effort, should be negated by the removal of the post. It feels like whoever took the effort has the reward taken away. Furthermore, what does it mean to remove the Privilege, which makes it seem as if the User never earned that Privilege.

Answer (score 12):

The link between reputation and privileges is "live" and immediate<sup>*</sup>, such that *all* reputation decreases cause a concomitant loss in privileges. This is very much by design, and is almost certainly not going to be special-cased for suggested edits.

The only question, then, is whether reputation should be lost for approved suggested edits on posts that have been deleted. I still say yes, because your edit no longer adds any value to the site. When the associated post gets deleted, it is as if your edit never happened.

Think of it as an encouragement to edit only posts that you expect will stick around. In other words, to borrow from the common (albeit coarse) Meta vernacular: don't "polish turds".

Note that reputation for deleted posts is handled in much the same way, with one minor exception: for extremely old posts that have gained a substantial number of upvotes (3 or more), you do get to keep the reputation gained. Otherwise, the reputation is lost, for the exact same reason: your erstwhile contributions are no longer adding value to the site. The exception for old, upvoted answers was added a few years back, as a concession to stem the tide of excess bellyaching by users that was creating friction when we tried to clean up old, off-topic questions.

See Also: [Should I keep the reputation from suggesting edits to deleted posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317354/should-i-keep-the-reputation-from-suggesting-edits-to-deleted-posts)

__
<sub>* Allowing for caching effects, of course. Check [here](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) to see if you should blame caching.</sub>

Comment: In my opinion it would be impossible to know at the onset of a question, especially one that required edits, whether or not it would stick around. Sometimes, one may find gems inside "turds" if only one were to explore [Allow me to also use Meta vernacular]. That being said, I agree that poor questions shouldn't live on the site, and rep from edits to those may have to be repealed. But rep and privilege from edits to questions that lived for a time as long as 2 months should stay, given that the question did survive initial scrutiny by the community and then was likely answered as well.

Comment: Update : I see you've answered that rep from edits to questions with 3 or more upvotes get to stay. A small consolation, but I stick to the earlier point about it being hard to predict certain questions. Also, people who are keen judges of a question would have already earned 1k rep, wherein they no longer receive rep from edits. Catch 22? :D